# How can I efficiently extract text from bunch for web pages without extra information

Tags: java, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have list of webpages around 1 million, I want to efficiently just extract text from those pages. Currently I am using BeautifulSoup library in python to get text from HTML and using request command to get html of a webpage. This approach extract some extra information in addition to the text like if any javascript is listed in body.

Could you please suggest me any suitable and efficient way to do the task. I looked at scrapy but it looks like it crawls specific website. Can we pass it list of specific webpages to get information from ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Samresh. First, you need to find a method that works for at least 1 page, then try to find an efficient method that would work for your million pages. Scrapy won't bring you any magic method that would gives a better result in term of content than requests and beautifulsoup. If you are happy with those results, you can do basically the same on scrapy, it will help you to parallelize the requests. If you are not happy with the result you had with beautifoulsoup, be aware that your problem is not easy to solve at all.

Comment: But "I looked at scrapy but it looks like it crawls specific website" is not true and of course you can pass a list of specific webpages : https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html (see the start_urls attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Scrapy to crawl a set of URLs in a generic fashion.

You simply need to set them on the `start_urls` list attribute of your spider, or reimplement the `start_requests` spider method to yield requests from any data source, and then implement your `parse` callback to perform the generic content extraction you want.

You can use [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text) to extract text from them, and regular Scrapy selectors to extract additional data like the one you mention.

Answer (score 0):

In scrapy you can set up your own parser. E.g. Beautiful soup. This parser you can call from your parse method.

To extract text from generic pages I traverse the body only, exclude comments etc and some tags like script, style, etc:

```
for snippet in soup.find('body').descendants:
    if isinstance(snippet, bs4.element.NavigableString) \
            and not isinstance(snippet, EXCLUDED_STRING_TYPES)\
            and snippet.parent.name not in EXCLUDED_TAGS:
        snippet = re.sub(UNICODE_WHITESPACES, ' ', snippet)
        snippet = snippet.strip()
        if snippet != '':
            snippets.append(snippet)
```

with

```
EXCLUDED_STRING_TYPES = (bs4.Comment, bs4.CData, bs4.ProcessingInstruction, bs4.Declaration)
EXCLUDED_TAGS = ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'pre', 'code']
UNICODE_WHITESPACES = re.compile(u'[\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f \x85\xa0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004'
                                 u'\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]+')
```